# Java Swing application, dialog checking for number in range

Tags: java, swing

I'm working on a card game with 1-4 players. When I start a new game it will instantiate a class `DialogCreator` that asks you to enter the number of players you want. Here is the code for the DialogCreator:

```
private class DialogCreator {
    /**
     * Creates a dialog for the input of how many players you want in the game.
     * Takes an integer between 1 and 4.
     * @param msg
     * @return
     */
    int createIntDialog(String msg) {
        String inValue = null;
        String error_msg = "";

        int v = 0;

        while ((inValue = JOptionPane
                .showInputDialog(msg + error_msg + ":")) != null) {
            error_msg = "";
            int inVal = Integer.parseInt(inValue);
            try {
                if(inVal >= 1 && inVal <= 4)
                    v = inVal;
                break;
            } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                error_msg = "(Entered values can only be integers between 1 and 4)";
            }
        }
        return v;
    }
}
```

I thought that this code would try to set `v = inVal` only if `1 <= inVal` `>= 4` and if `inVal` is < 1 or > 4 it would go to catch and give me the error message. This does not work and I get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` if I enter a number that is not between 1 and 4. It works fine to check if I enter a `String` that can not be parsed to `int`. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: The error message is only changed if you don't enter an integer, not if `inVal` is <1 or >4. You have to add an else block after the `if(inVal >= 1 && inVal <= 4)` block in order to do that. Also, `int inVal = Integer.parseInt(inValue);` should be inside the try block, otherwise the catch block has no effect. I don't know why you get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, after changing your code a little bit it all works for me.

Comment: Is there a particular reason for you to use exception handling as flow control? This is actually no good style. I'd check the input with some regex of at least make `TryParse` instead of a cast that leads to an exception in the catch block.

Comment: It's the only method I'm familiar with and I'm in a hurry to finish this project. That's why I haven't searched for better ways to handle exceptions. Thanks for pointing it out though. I will research other methods for future projects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
if(inVal >= 1 && inVal <= 4)
    v = inVal;
break;
```

Without any braces, only the `v = inVal;` is under the if statement. Therefore, whatever `inVal` is, you are going to break out of the while loop and return 0 (`v` was initialized to 0). Then I guess that if this method returns 0, the rest of your code fails. If you add braces around then you can assure that you will break only if the input is valid:

```
if(inVal >= 1 && inVal <= 4) {
    v = inVal;
    break;
}
```

As a side-note, you should be consistent with your namings: `error_msg` doesn't respect Java naming conventions.

Comment: Thanks! That fixed the problem. Also, I'll keep your side-note in mind, thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

A simpler solution is to just use a `JOptionPane` with a combo box containing the values 1-4. Then there is no need for any edit checking.

Read the section from the tutorial on [Getting User Input From a Dialog](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html#input) for an example showing how this is done.

Or if you want to insist that the user enter a number then the tutorial also contains a section on `Stopping Automatic Dialog Closing`, which is a little more complicated, but a better overall solution for using the JOptionPane.